# Align Image in Center of Section and Be Relative to the Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

Within my website, I am making this section inside the `<body>` tag. Here is a snippet:

```
<div id="section" class="featurecontent">
    <section>
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="Featured article">
        <p class="pnews">Featured Article - Description </p>
        <hr>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is the relevant CSS code, including the section being relative to the browser stated via `position: relative;` statement.

```
#section{
    display: block;
    padding:3px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    height:70%;
    width: 35%;
    border-width: 3px;
}

.featurecontent{
    height: 1100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-width: 2px;
    line-height: 0.5;
    padding: 1px;   
}
```

How would I place the image relatively center to the section block (instead of being placed in the left), and adjust itself relative to the size of the browser similar to the section block? I am aware `align="middle"` does not work for HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

You have a whole bunch of unnecessary code... all you need is:

```
#section {
  position: relative;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.featurecontent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the image, which I assume is the aim, simply add the code next to the comment to your current CSS.

```
.featurecontent{
    height: 1100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-width: 2px;
    line-height: 0.5;
    padding: 1px;   
    text-align: center; /* New line of code to center img */
}
```